# Why composite of primary key with other (not null) columns not automatically unique in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, primary-key, unique-constraint

When create two tables using the following queries in PostgreSQL:

```
 create table test_unique_pk (
    id serial primary key,
    value varchar not null
 );

 create table refer_unique_pk (
    id integer,
    value varchar,
    foreign key (id, value) references test_unique_pk(id, value)
 );
```

I got

```
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "test_unique_pk".
```

If I modify the first table to

```
 create table test_unique_pk (
     id serial primary key,
     value varchar not null,
     unique(id, value)
 );
```

It just works fine.

However since primary key is already unique, in my opinion, the composite `(id, value)` should also be unique, since we can not construct two tuples with same `id`, and thus we can not construct two equal tuples of `(id, value)`.

If the above statement is correct, why PostgreSQL does not automatically add a unique constraint on composite references including primary key?

Comment: Why would you want to add the `value` column as part of the foreign key to begin with if `id` is already unique`?

Comment: Because that's the way they defined the language. This question cannot be answered without asking the designers. If you just want confirmation that a superset of a unique column set is unique, edit your question to ask that, and you are correct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I need to keep the table `test_unique_pk` and the table `refer_unique_pk` have the same `id` and `value`. thus the database should reject rows like `test_unique_pk(id = 3, value="test"), refer_unique_pk(id = 3, value="other")`.

Comment: To avoid duplication the `value` column should not be present in one of the `refer_unique_pk` or `test_unique_pk` tables. The `id` column is enough to ensure uniquness so if you were to need the value it should be fetched via a join.

Answer (score 0):

The definiton of a Primary Key is to be unique and not null at the same time. A NULL value is always like an "unknow" value, so you can't use this insite a PK.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp